# How to get scale, rotation & translation after feature tracking?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I have implemented a Kanade–Lucas–Tomasi feature tracker. I have used it on two images, that show the same scene, but the camera has moved a bit between taking the pictures.

As a result I get the coordinates of the features. For example:

```
1. Picture:
| feature | (x,y)=val       |
|---------|-----------------|
| 1       | (436,349)=33971 |
| 2       | (440,365)=29648 |
| 3       | ( 36,290)=29562 |

2nd Picture:
| feature | (x,y)=val    |
|---------|--------------|
| 1 | (443.3,356.0)=0    |
| 2 | (447.6,373.0)=0    |
| 3 | ( -1.0, -1.0)=-4   |
```

So I know the position of the features 1 & 2 in both images and that feature 3 couldn't be found in the second image. The coordinates of the features 1 & 2 aren't the same, because the camera has zoomed in a bit and also moved.

Which algorithm is suitable to get the scale, rotation and translation between the two images? Is there a robust algorithm, that also considers outliers?

Comment: Question is too broad. Suggest you read some references on the topic of "structure from motion" and refocus.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know what movement happened between the images, then you need to calculate the Homography between them. The homography however, needs 4 points to be calculated.

If you have 4 points in both images, that are relatively on a plane (same flat surface, e.g. a window), then you can follow the steps from [here in math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/how-to-compute-homography-matrix-h-from-corresponding-points-2d-2d-planar-homog) to compute the homography matrix that will transform between images.

Note that while rotation and translation may happen between 2 images, they also could have been taken from different angles. If this happens, then the homography is your only option. Instead, if the images are for sure just rotation and translation (e.g. 2 satelite images) then you may find some other method, but homography will also help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Depending upon whether the camera is calibrated or uncalibrated, tracked features to compute essential or fundamental matrix respectively.
2. Factorize the matrix into R, T. Use Multiview geometry book for any help with the formulae. https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook1/HZepipolar.pdf

Caution: These steps only work well if the features come from different depth planes and cover wide field of view. In case all features lie on a single plane, you should estimate homography and try to factorize that instead.